# How to remove | Symbol from start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried the following code to remove | symbol from stand and end bus it does not work.

```
"|aabckdoio|".replace("/^\|/g","").replace("/\|$/","")
```

Comment: You have to pass a regular expression to `.replace`, not a string (at least in this case). I.e. `/^\|/g` instead of `"/^\|/g"`. Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I think any thing between // considered as regex

Comment: If it is in the source "by itself", yes. But your `/.../` is inside a string literal. Consider `var foo = "var bar";`. It does declare a variable `foo` but not a variable `bar`, because `"var bar"` is a string. The string is not evaluated as JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for you, without using regexs. Uses [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [String.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf?redirect=no) and [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) (could have used [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with slightly modified `end` index), but it only removes the start or end characters if they match the given arguments. Errors in arguments are quiet (except `null` or `undefined`), and you may want them to be noisy and if so then just change the checking to suit your style/project.

Javascript

```
var testString1 = "|aabckdoio|",
    testString2 = "*|aabckdoio|*";

function trimChars(string, startCharacters /*, endCharacters */ ) {
    string = {}.valueOf.call(string).toString();
    startCharacters  = {}.valueOf.call(startCharacters).toString();

    var start = 0,
        end = string.length,
        startCharactersLength = startCharacters.length,
        endCharacters = startCharacters,
        endCharactersLength = startCharactersLength;

    if (arguments.length > 2) {
        endCharacters = {}.valueOf.call(arguments[2]).toString();
        endCharactersLength = endCharacters.length;
    }

    if (string.indexOf(startCharacters) === 0) {
        start = startCharactersLength;
    }

    if (string.lastIndexOf(endCharacters) === end - endCharactersLength) {
        end -= endCharactersLength;
    }

    return string.slice(start, end);
}

console.log(trimChars(testString1, "|"));
console.log(trimChars(testString2, "*|", "|*"));
```

output

```
aabckdoio
aabckdoio
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/znpG5/)

Answer (score 4):

It *would* work, if you removed the double quotes from the regexes.

If you pass a string to `.replace()` it performs a *normal* string search and replace, not a regex search.

You can also combine the two `.replace` operations:

```
"|aabckdoio|".replace(/^\||\|$/g, "");
```

Also, if you know for certain that the `|` characters will always be there, you can do it without a regex at all:

```
"|aabckdoio|".slice(1, -1)
```

Comment: This only remove the starting | symbol

Comment: @AbdulBasit For a few seconds there was a version without the `g` modifier - the version here works (on Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

If you just have to remove first and last character you can use:

```
var str = "|aabckdoio|".slice(1, -1); 
str; // "aabckdoio"
```

Comment: ha, overlapped edits - I was adding the `.slice()` method at the same time as you added this answer